# Remove "[ ]" from a column in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to remove the brackes '[', ']' from a column in a pyspark data frame and keep the data inside it.

The data frame looks like this -

```
+--------+---------------+-------+------------+
|  app_Id|         doc_id|doc_typ|        date|
+--------+---------------+-------+------------+
|12000015|FASWI4EVPPOPPYS|   SPEC|[2007-12-06]|
|12000022|FA33AVYGPPOPPYS|   ABST|[2007-12-07]|
|12000038|FA3WODYZPPOPPYS|   SPEC|[2007-12-07]|
|12000038|FA3WODZLPPOPPYS|    CLM|[2007-12-07]|
|12000054|GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS|    CLM|[2011-07-25]|
+--------+---------------+-------+------------+
```

But I need the brackets removed from the date field leaving only the date.  This is shown in the example below.

```
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|  app_Id|         doc_id|doc_typ|      date|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|12000015|FASWI4EVPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-06|
|12000022|FA33AVYGPPOPPYS|   ABST|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODYZPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODZLPPOPPYS|    CLM|2007-12-07|
|12000054|GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS|    CLM|2011-07-25|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refrain from using images if you can paste the actual text/data itself. This makes it easier to view, replicate and provide an answer.

Comment: What data type is that column? It is just strings?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
  ('12000015','FASWI4EVPPOPPYS','SPEC','[2007-12-06]')
,('12000022','FA33AVYGPPOPPYS','ABST','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000038','FA3WODYZPPOPPYS','SPEC','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000038','FA3WODZLPPOPPYS','CLM','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000054','GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS','CLM','[2011-07-25]')
  ], ['app_Id','doc_id', 'doc_typ', 'date']
)

df.withColumn('date', regexp_replace(regexp_replace('date', '\\[', ''),'\\]', '')).show()
```

```
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|  app_Id|         doc_id|doc_typ|      date|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|12000015|FASWI4EVPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-06|
|12000022|FA33AVYGPPOPPYS|   ABST|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODYZPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODZLPPOPPYS|    CLM|2007-12-07|
|12000054|GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS|    CLM|2011-07-25|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
  ('12000015','FASWI4EVPPOPPYS','SPEC','[2007-12-06]')
,('12000022','FA33AVYGPPOPPYS','ABST','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000038','FA3WODYZPPOPPYS','SPEC','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000038','FA3WODZLPPOPPYS','CLM','[2007-12-07]')
,('12000054','GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS','CLM','[2011-07-25]')
  ], ['app_Id','doc_id', 'doc_typ', 'date']
)

df = df.withColumn("date",(F.regexp_replace("date","[\[\]]", "")))
df.show()
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|  app_Id|         doc_id|doc_typ|      date|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
|12000015|FASWI4EVPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-06|
|12000022|FA33AVYGPPOPPYS|   ABST|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODYZPPOPPYS|   SPEC|2007-12-07|
|12000038|FA3WODZLPPOPPYS|    CLM|2007-12-07|
|12000054|GQNPYCKXPPOPPYS|    CLM|2011-07-25|
+--------+---------------+-------+----------+
```